# Elasticsearch: Get processor fields/types?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to get information on the available processors in a cluster. I know I can give the following command to get a list of processor names...

```
GET /_nodes/ingest
```

but I'm interested in also getting the information(field names would probably be enough) about each processor. I'm trying to make building pipelines a little bit easier on my client side and wanted to get the info from elastic but I'm having trouble seeing a way to do that.

Thanks

Comment: What you are looking for is the cat API https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cat-plugins.html

Comment: So that shows plugins, which isn't quite processors or their fields. And I want access to the built in processors as well. Unless I'm not reading something correctly